# php email form redirects incorrectly after sending

Tags: php, html, html-email

I'm using a template for my website that I found online. It came with a contact form html page and a sendmail php file. The form works and I receive the email in my inbox, but, for some reason, after I hit the 'send' button, the browser redirects to a blank page with the following (error?) message:

```
" {"nameMessage":"","emailMessage":"","messageMessage":""} "
```

The only thing that I can think of that I've changed (in the php file) is the email address where the messages are sent.

I am wondering  how I can avoid this message and redirect to another page (thanks.html) instead?

Specifically, what code do I need to add, remove or replace to fix this issue please?

Here is the HTML and PHP code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="contact-us container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="contact-form span7" html_id="contactfrm">
                <p>Want to get in touch? Use the form below to send an email.</p>
                <form method="post" action="assets/sendmail.php">
                    <label for="name" class="nameLabel">Name</label>
                      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
                    <label for="email" class="emailLabel">Email</label>
                      <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                      <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your subject...">
                    <label for="message" class="messageLabel">Message</label>
                      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
                    <button id="button">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'email@gmail.com';

    $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
    $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    }
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }
    if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
        // Send email
    $headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

p.s. I've noticed that there have been previous posts regarding this issue but I'm quite a newbie (especially with PHP).

Comment: your output is the resut of `echo json_encode($array);` what did you want to happen after sending ?

Comment: I want it to redirect to an html page of my choosing (i.e. thanks.html)

Comment: use php's `header()` function for that

Comment: `echo json_encode($array);` remove this and also try to do like :- `if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers)){redirection code(send to some other page with some message if mail successful)}else{ return back to form page with error message}`

Comment: pr otip- validate email the easy way: `if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  //valid
}`

Answer (score 0):

After you have written

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

write ,

```
header('Location:thanks.php');
```

this will redirect you to thanks.php page and there you can write your html/php code.

Comment: what kind of errors ? may be headers improperly sent . this guy probably does'nt know how redirection works. Let him atleast get the code working and then later we can discuss on the good and bad practices.

Comment: the error will be: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

Comment: for now this will work as we are redirecting him to php later he can add header information also.

Comment: no you dont get it. you suggest output before the header call

Comment: Here's text from manual `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: so then header can be added before echo is called ?

Comment: yes but it would be pointless as you would never see what was echoed having been redirected before hand

Comment: I added header('Location:thanks.php'); and I created a thanks.php file and put it in the root folder but there was no change. (still got redirected to " {"nameMessage":"","emailMessage":"","messageMessage":""} ")

Comment: I removed //echo json_encode($array); 
and replaced it with 

header('Location: thanks.php');
which solved the problem. Thanks very much for all of your help.